# Unable to install the package: 'azure-ai-vision-computervision' via pip

Tags: python, pip

Unable to install the package via:

```
pip install azure-ai-vision-computervision
```

which throws the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Ashok/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/Comp.py", line 1, in <module>
    from azure.ai.vision import ComputerVisionClient
ImportError: cannot import name 'ComputerVisionClient' from 'azure.ai.vision' (C:\Users\Ashok\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\azure\ai\vision\__init__.py)
```

While we run the script showing the above error
we are expecting the solution for this error